# Change Screen Resolution in Acer E1900HQ

Tags: display, resolution

I am using **Acer E1900HQ** Monitor, I need to Change Screen resolution like **1920*1080** but, Monitor shows only **1366 x 768** I searched about Acer E1900HQ Specification http://www.amazon.in/Acer-E1900HQ-18-5-inch-LED-Monitor/dp/B019SQK68C Specification also Show **1366 x 768**.

I need to change my Monitor Resolution into **1920*1080**  Is there any way to change my screen resolution? If there Suggest me How to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum resolution on that particular monitor is 1366*768.

The monitor does not support 1920x1080